# Why is the compiler not recognizing this type alias?

Tags: elm, type-alias

does anyone know why the compiler isn't recognizing this type alias?

```
viewBoardCanvas : Model -> Html Msg
viewBoardCanvas model =
    case model.game of
        Nothing -> Options.div [] [ Button.render Mdl [ 0 ] model.mdl [] [ text "Start Game" ] ]
        Just Game -> text "I'm a game!"
```

It says it can't find pattern game, but in my *Types.elm* file I have.

```
type alias Game = { board : Html Msg , players : List Player }

type alias Model = { resume : List ResumeSections , mdl : Material.Model , route : Route , game : Maybe Game }
```

Answer (score 4):

In Elm, variable names have to begin with lowercase. In your `Just Game` case, the problem is that `Game` is uppercase.

Change it to the following and it should work:

```
Just game -> text "I'm a game!"
```